# Submitting awk scripts as jobs in a server

Tags: awk, slurm

I'm trying to run the awk script bellow in several files as individual tasks in a server using SLURM job array.

array.sh:

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2 > file3
awk -f script.awk file1 file21 > file34
awk -f script.awk file1 file22 > file35
awk -f script.awk file1 file23 > file36
```

script.awk:

```
FNR==NR {
        n = ++q[$1]
        min[$1 FS n] = $2
        max[$1 FS n] = $3
        next
    }

    # process file1
    n = q[$1] { # if no q entry, line cannot be in range
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            if ( min[$1 FS i]<=$2 && $2<=max[$1 FS i]) {
                print
                next
            }
    }
```

Each individual awk cmd in the array works fine when I run live in the shell as in `awk -f script.awk file1 file2 | head` , but the same cmd will produce an empty output when asked to write to output as in `awk -f script.awk file1 file2 > file3`

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -p batch
#SBATCH --job-name="firstrun"
#SBATCH --mem=30g
#SBATCH -t 48:00:00
#SBATCH -o /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/stdout/%A_%a.stdout
#SBATCH --array=1-4

eval $(sed "${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}q;d" array.sh)
```

I tried  with  `#!/bin/bash x+` so I could check what's going on but still not clear.

and the log files show

```
==> 15103044_1.stdout <==
++ sed '1q;d' array.sh
+ eval awk -f script.awk file1 file2 '>' file3 
++ awk -f script.awk file1 file2
```

I also tried submitting this as

```
in=("file2", "file21", "file22", file23")

awk -f script.awk file1 file2 ${in[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]} > ${in[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}.test
```

But it continues to generate empty files, and this is what I find in the log

```
==> 15103056_1.stdout <==
+ in=("file2", "file21", "file22", "file23")
+ awk -f script.awk file1 file2
```

ADDED sample files

file1

```
A       1       1
A       20      1
B       17      1
B       33      1
C       10      1
C       20      1
E       7       1
```

file 2

```
A       1       5       1
A       6       20      1
B       1       10      1
B       30      60      1
C       10      20      1
E       1       6       1
```

output file3

```
A       1       1
A       20      1
B       33      1
C       10      1
C       20      1
```

Comment: You could change the first line (shebang) with `#!/bin/bash -x` (note the extra `-x`) to see exactly what happens exactly

Comment: Hard to tell how `slurm` is affecting the processing. Agree with above, maybe `-x` will show something. I'm also surprized that you say this works from the command line. To debug, what is the output from `sed "${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}q;d" array.sh` ? I did a quick test, and the best I could get was that it printed the first line of the file and then quits. Not sure why you have the `;d`  (I know `;d` is `sed` delete). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've updated my question to show what happens. I'm still unclear on what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried to isolate awk from this issue (it seems like an issue about using slurm)? For example add 4 simple lines, like "echo 1"  and run it, and then try writing to file maybe, "echo 1 > file1" etc and see, first if you get output and second if you write to file. Also into these logs, I am not sure what exactly is logged but the command is printed without the redirection to the file for both cases. Is that expected?

Comment: A lot of little pieces here. 1) a) what do you expect to happen from `eval $(sed "${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}q;d" array.sh)`? b) I can't see how the eval is helping or what you hope to achieve with that c) unclear why you are using `$( cmd-substittion)` in that cmd. Did you want `var=$(eval $( sed ... ) )` ? d) again, the `sed` command doesn't make much sense, please describe in the body of your question what that is supposed to achieve. Do you understand and agree that the `set -x` output for the `sed` line is what you hoped for? As you have a `d` (delete) cmd included, did you want to delete ....

Comment: that line? If so you have to save the file. Most `linux` seds now support `sed -i 'cmds' file` to save a file "in-place". 2) Unclear where `in=...` is being used, inside slurm? I see the `> ${in[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}.test`, but unclear what that index is doing. Addin more sample data and `set -x` traces to your Q may help. ..... Your edits helped improve your Q, but maybe you see it is still unclear to someone on the outside. Good luck.

Comment: Hello, ok It seems like the script.awk, the array.sh, and the two ways of submitting the tasks are good. My files big. For example, file2 = 194411211 lines. Could the problem be the way awk does arrays? Does it only writes to file once has done all the calcs? I tested with smaller sample files and all works fine (the script, and the array submission).

Comment: Added tested sample files